# why empty string is 0x20?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Here is my solidity code.

```
contract TestLog {
    bytes constant internal EMPTY_BYTES = "";
    event Logempty(bytes data);
    function Log() public {
        emit Logempty(EMPTY_BYTES);
    }
}
```

so everythime I execute Log()，it print 0x20 in event log, why not 0x00 ?
I deployed it on Ropsten network. Here is the link:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xb0723e0943b7b10c985365df6aef983bc6eeb6d6#events

Comment: Outside of the fact that 0x20 is an ASCII "space" ("blank" character), I don't know.  Q: Is there any reason it matters?  Or just curiosity?

Comment: I am  just curious.

Answer (score 1):

Because the ASCII code of a blank space is actually 0x20. You can read more about those [here](https://bluesock.org/%7Ewillg/dev/ascii).

To clarify:

What you are using there, `""`, is actually the empty string and in most programming languages is different from null. So being a string of length zero, as it's also stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_string), there is also memory required to store it.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: That begs the question "Why is Log()" writing a "space"?  Instead of nothing at all?

Comment: but that doesn't make any sense. Why 0x20,not 0x00.

Comment: thanks，that helps a lot. I think I'll read the ethereum source code to find the answer.